# Clean mysqldump for tracking schema in git

Tags: mysql, git, version-control

I want to write a set of small shell scripts to help me keep MySQL schema in git. But one crux is that `mysqldump -uuser -ppass -d devdb > schema.sql` includes two things that change over time even if there are no schema changes:

- `AUTO_INCREMENT=[some number]` at the end of the definition of any table that has an auto-incremented column
- `-- Dump completed on [date and time]` at the end

I have scoured the web for ways to get a dump without those things, to no avail. Can you advise? Or should I be using a different command or tool to get a clean schema for use in version control?

EDIT: I just now found the `--skip-dump-date` option, so that solves point #2, but I still can't get rid of the auto-increment number without losing the other table attributes (or whatever you call those things) like the engine and the default character set.

Comment: Maybe look into using a tool like Liquibase.  From what I have seen, a better approach would be to keep track of the change sets between each version of your schema.

Comment: I had never heard of Liquibase, but at first glance it looks useful. It's not clear how that would integrate smoothly with a git repo (it sounds like a separate VCS), but I'll have to study it further. Yes, change sets would be nice, as long as the algorithm is smart enough to know when the change can be non-destructive - mysqldiff is a handy tool, but it's pretty dumb - if I rename a column, even if everything else stays the same, its suggested "change" is to drop and re-add the column! :-o

Comment: Ah, I see - Liquibase doesn't try to guess what you want done; you need to write the change set yourself (beforehand, and let it change the dev DB). That feels like more work in the short-term, but I see the merits down the road. I still haven't found a tutorial that covers the whole workflow (including integrating in a git repo), but I'll keep studying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to bypass #1, check https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=20786.

As noted in the comments section, you can use that sed command to filter it out (unless you have some CREATE TABLE statements that use it).

Comment: Yikes, a 10-year-old bug! I guess that shows the value of completely open-source software - if this weren't Oracle's baby, anyone could write a fix and submit a pull request. The sed command works - thanks.

Comment: Anyone can write a fix and submit a pull request. You just have to sign the OCA :) Glad to hear it worked for you!

Comment: I had to look up "OCA" - if it means "Oracle Certified Associate", apparently you have to buy and pass a test in Java proficiency - still sounds corporate to me. Anyway, I'm just a user - I don't write Java anyway.